# How do I parse this HTML with Jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I am trying to extract "Know your tractor" and "Shell Petroleum Company.1955"? Bear in mind that that is just a snippet of the whole code and there are more then one H2/H3 tag. And I would like to get the data from all the H2 and H3 tags.

Heres the HTML: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pif3B.png

The Code I have just now is:

```
    ArrayList<String> arrayList  = new ArrayList<String>();
    Document doc = null;
 try{

     doc = Jsoup.connect("http://primo.abdn.ac.uk:1701/primo_library/libweb/action/search.do?dscnt=0&scp.scps=scope%3A%28ALL%29&frbg=&tab=default_tab&dstmp=1332103973502&srt=rank&ct=search&mode=Basic&dum=true&indx=1&tb=t&vl(freeText0)=tractor&fn=search&vid=ABN_VU1").get();
     Elements heading = doc.select("h2.EXLResultTitle span"); 

     for (Element src : heading) {
            String j = src.text();
            System.out.println(j);  //check whats going into the array 
            arrayList.add(j);
     }
```

How would I extract "Know your tractor" and "Shell Petroleum Company.1955"?   Thanks for your help!

Comment: How would I extract "Know your tractor" and "Shell Petroleum Company.1955"?

Comment: Now *that* is what I call a good question.  +1  BTW - it is preferable to paste textual content of the HTML (in code tags) than link to an image or screenshot.

Comment: You may want to add a HTML snippet from the URl (http://primo.abdn.ac.uk:1701/primo_library/libweb/action/search.do?dscnt=0&scp.scps=scope%3A%28ALL%29&frbg=&tab=default_tab&dstmp=1332103973502&srt=rank&ct=search&mode=Basic&dum=true&indx=1&tb=t&vl(freeText0)=tractor&fn=search&vid=ABN_VU1). Or even better, generalise your question to "how do I extract the text from all/certain h2 and h3 elements on a page"? Coincidentally, I was surprised to find that Aberdeen uses the same library searching software as my university.

Comment: It seams after using BalusC answer, it still did not return anything. When I look at the source of the html page I can see all of the information but when I println 'doc' it is not present. Is this because of JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selector only selects `<span>` elements which are inside `<h2 class="EXLResultTitle">`, while you *actually* need those `<h2>` elements themself. So, just remove `span` from the selector:

```
Elements headings = doc.select("h2.EXLResultTitle");

for (Element heading : headings) {
    System.out.println(heading.text());
}
```

You should be able to figure the selector for `<h3 class="EXLResultAuthor">` yourself based on the lesson learnt.

#### See also:

- [Jsoup cookbook - CSS selectors](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)
- [Jsoup `Selector` API documentation](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html)

Comment: It seams after using BalusC answer, it still did not return anything. When I look at the source of the html page I can see all of the information but when I println 'doc' it is not present. Is this because of JavaScript?

Comment: Apparently the request URL is wrong or the response is dependent on other request factors (parameters, cookies, etc). Verify them with the webbrowser developer tool.