# How to parse HTML tags using Jsoup in android

Tags: android, html, parsing, android-activity, jsoup

I am developing an android application in which I am parsing html contents from a website using Jsoup in android.

`<meta name="title" content="Notices for the week - Holy Family Church, Pestom Sagar" />`

For this I've wrote:

```
 @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                // Connect to the web site
                org.jsoup.nodes.Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                // Get the html document title   
                title=document.select("meta[name=title]");
                desc = title.attr("content");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch(NullPointerException ex){
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
            return null; 
        }
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {
            // Set title into TextView
            t1.setText(desc);
        }
```

This is working fine without any problem and displaying in textView of Activity. Now I want to parse h3 tag from that website.

```
<h3 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="sites-page-title-header" style="" align="left">
<span id="sites-page-title" dir="ltr">Notices for the week</span>
</h3>
```

I am not getting any idea how to do this and display this using TextView in android activity. Please suggest me...Also if I want to parse whole div tag and display that into activity using textView..!!!

Comment: Try this                   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114282/how-can-you-parse-html-in-android                                                                    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762857/how-do-i-parse-this-html-with-jsoup

Comment: Where is the problem at parsing? Selecting `h3`-tags out of the document works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select h3 tag directly as :

```
String h3=document. select("h3").text();
textView.setText(h3);
```

Or

```
 textView. setText(document.select("span[id=sites-page-title]").first().text());
```